# Is it possible to omit certain tags when looking at new questions?

Tags: support, tags

I am wondering whether it is possible to omit certain tags when looking at new questions posted. For example, I want to view Java questions, yet I do not want any questions with the Android tag.

Is this possible?

Thank you,

Dean

Comment: On the right hand pane on SO of the Questions page, there is a section "Favorite Tags".  You can choose tags to mark as favorites or ignore.  You can then further choose to grey out or hide ignored tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Just place a `-` sign before the word you would like to omit.

Example: `java  -android`: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+-android

In the example, you'll see to the right side of the page:

[image]